# Scientific character in tech related bachelor thesis

Tags: computer-science, writing, science, technology

So I am currently on the task to find a question or specific topic for my bachelor thesis.
The field I am looking in is the micro service approach.
There are few topics I consider writing about, e.g. evaluating technologies (e.g. Netflix stack, docker, kubernetes ..), challenges of microservices and how technologies deal with them (resilence, performance, load balancing, scalability), analysing/evaluating state of the art technologies (probably new trends and such).
I would like to hear if you think these topics are having a scientific character or if its more some kind of summation.

Comment: Whichever one you pick is for you to discuss the suitability with your advisor.